# Maps SDK - Set floating text besides a marker (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I achieve setting a floating text besides a marker, just like any point of interest you can see in Google Map? (see below picture)

"Info Window" is not what I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: While not a solution, unclear if you are aware of: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils which has source for inspiration.